# Is there a way to avoid X-Frame-Options in a CEF Windows Chromium Desktop App?

Tags: reactjs, windows, servicestack, chromium-embedded

I created a simple app using the suggested "app init", then I dropped a pre-compiled ReactApp in place.
The app has a browser within it that uses an IFrame to host the navigated pages, but in some pages, it issues the following error:

Refused to display 'https://www.theverge.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.", source: http://localhost:5000/#/

https://content-security-policy.com/

The page above has a series of ways to how this could be avoided, and Chromium has a flag that could help, where it disables security and as many suggested in other posts and questions, that may help with this issue.

Beyond those, there is the possibility of writing a reverse-proxy that could potentially take care of this.

Either way what I need to know is if there is a way to achieve that through parameters within the "app" tool, something like:

```
app --unsecure
app publish --unsecure
app publish-exe --unsecure
```

Thank you

Comment: From a quick look it [doesn't appear it can be disabled in CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1520/can-not-disable-web_security) I'll have a look later tonight to see if it's possible in a [Custom .NET Core Desktop App](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-windows-desktop#custom-net-core-desktop-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a number of different options inclusing using a [Custom .NET Core Desktop Apps](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-windows-desktop#custom-net-core-desktop-apps) that adds the `disable-web-security` switch which used to work:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000/")
        .Build();

    host.StartAsync();

    var config = new CefConfig(Debug)
    {
        Args = args,
        StartUrl = startUrl,
        HideConsoleWindow = false,
        OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing = (processType, commandLine) => {
            commandLine.AppendSwitch("disable-web-security");                    
        }
    };

    return CefPlatformWindows.Start(config);
}
```

But no longer does so appears this security restriction is now embedded inside of Blink.

#### Using a Proxy to Remove Headers

The only solution I could get to work is to use a proxy that calls the internal .NET Core server which proxies the downstream URL but ignoring the `X-Frame-Options` header.

This is easy to do using ServiceStack's [Proxy Feature](https://docs.servicestack.net/proxy-feature) where you can register a proxy to https://www.theverge.com that strips the `X-Frame-Options` header with:

```
Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
    matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/theverge"),
    resolveUrl: req => $"https://www.theverge.com" + req.RawUrl.Replace("/theverge", "/")) {
    IgnoreResponseHeaders = {
        "X-Frame-Options"
    }
});
```

This will let you embed The Verge in your App with:

```
<iframe src="/theverge" style="width:100%; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Which will render TheVerge in an iframe as expected:

[image]

### Working Demo

You can find a working example of this in [ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.CefGlue/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore):

#### [Startup.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.CefGlue/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore/Startup.cs)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost());

        app.Run(context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/metadata");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }
}

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("MyApp", typeof(MyServices).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature());

        Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
            matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/theverge"),
            resolveUrl: req => "https://www.theverge.com" + 
                                req.RawUrl.Replace("/theverge", "/")) {
            IgnoreResponseHeaders = {
                "X-Frame-Options"
            }
        });
    }
}

[Route("/hello")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request) => 
        new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
}
```

#### [ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore.csproj](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.CefGlue/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore/ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore.csproj)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64" Version="5.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="5.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.CefGlue" Version="5.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64" Version="5.*" />
<PackageReference Include="WinApi" Version="4.0.0" />
```

You'll also need to copy CEF binaries from the `ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64` NuGet package with:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="locales\*.*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="swiftshader\*.*">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="*.pak">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="*.lib">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="*.dat">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="*.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="*.bin">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="*.exe">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)"
            DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)\%(Content.Link)"
            SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
            OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

#### [index.html](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.CefGlue/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.CefGlue.Win64.AspNetCore/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>X-Frame-Options Proxy Test</h1>
    <iframe src="/theverge" style="width:100%; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this later today and will let you know if it did the job.
It might not, since the user can navigate to any page, its a browser, the verge is just one example of the problem, but I will see how I can adapt this. Thank you.

Comment: Tried running the app, but all I get is a blank page, it seems like its never reaching the index.html page